# How to condense these nested for loops into list comprehension in python with dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm trying to take one row at a time from dataframe 1, and check it against all rows of dataframe 2, and according to conditions update another column in dataframe 1.

I've got this working with nested for loops but how can this  be condensed with list comprehension?

Here's a simplified example of what works using nested for loops. It's doing "if every entry i of column c1 in df1 is less than **every** entry in column d1 of df2, then update column c3 of df1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'c1': 1, 'c3': "0"}, {'c1': 3, 'c3': "0"}, {'c1': 10, 'c3': "0"}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'d1': 3}, {'d1': 7}])

print(df1)
print(df2)

for i in df1.index:
    for j in df2.index:
        if df1.loc[i, "c1"] < df2.loc[j, "d1"]:
            df1.loc[i, "c3"] = 0
        else:
            df1.loc[i, "c3"] = 1

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

I've done similar updates using a solution of type

```
df1.loc[*some condition which specifies the applicable rows of df1* eg df1["c1"] > df2["d1"], c3] = 1
```

but that will only work when the rows of df1 and df2 are 1:1, and wouldn't compare each row of df1 to all the rows of df2 anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your desired output? I'm sure there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if every entry in `df1['c1']` with `max(df2['d1'])` to check `""if every entry i of column c1 in df1 is less than every entry in column d1 of df2,"` that would ensure comparison condition. Accordingly set `c3` to `1`. Consider below code.

```
df1.loc[df1['c1'] > max(df2['d1']), 'c3'] = 1
```

Output:

```
   c1   c3
0   1   0
1   3   0
2   10  1
```

Note: the output matches with OP's `df1` after the for loop logic.

Answer (score 1):

I found the inner loop to be redundant as the modification finally depends on the last value of d1 of df2.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

With his assumption, I have written this.

```
df1.c3=[0  if df1.loc[i, "c1"] < df2.loc[df2.index[-1], "d1"] else 1 for i in df1.index]   
print(df1)
print(df2)



   c1  c3
0   1   0
1   3   0
2  10   1
   d1
0   3
1   7
```

Comment: In this example, yes that is correct that the check would depend on the last (or largest) value in df1, however I am working with unknown data sets until run-time so can't assume that the largest value will always be in index -1. Thanks for the solution though.